# Laravel data returns wrapped in an array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
{"data":[{"id":1,etc....}]}
```

would like an object

```
{"data": {etc...}}}
```

Comment: You are calling the collection by `get()` if you want a model instance the replace it with `first()` as Aashish gaba said in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's giving an array because you have used `get()` . It always returns an array of instances that satisfy the condition.

If you want a single object as you've stated in the post, you need to use `first()`, like this

`Product::where('slug', $product)->with('stuff')->first();`

This will get you the very first entry the matches the criteria.